# Is it possible for like master pages in windows forms applications

Tags: winforms

Is it possible for like master pages in windows forms applications?

Comment: You will have to try to explain this a little better. Your question is very inclear.

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance.  Any properties of and controls on a base form are inherited by a derived form.